# Run python script located on computer with aws s3 folder object as input parameter in an ec2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a python script that takes a folder of pdfs as an input, and outputs an excel file in the current directory. In terminal I would enter the line below and an excel file would appear in the current directory.

$python3 script.py folder

I was wondering how to run this script with a folder located in an aws s3 bucket as the input without having to download the folder because it is pretty big. I believe you have to use an ec2 instance but am unclear about the whole process, especially how to have the s3 folder object be the input parameter for the python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS SDK (Boto3) in Python to list content of S3 bucket, get each object and perform operations on it.

Here's how you normally do it:

1. Get access to s3 client handler:
   [Get Boto3 S3 Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client)
2. List S3 Bucket Objects:
   [List S3 Bucket Objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#list_objects)
3. Iterate the list and get object:
   [Get Each Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)
4. Perform whatever operations you're looking for on each object.

Moreover, you can use generators with python to make the application memory optimized while iterating over list.

**Note: If you're using EC2, it's a best practice to attached the IAM role with permissions to the specific bucket you're trying to list.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) to list the contents of an S3 location and stream the contents of each S3 object. The parameter you would pass to the script would be an S3 url like `s3://my-bucket/my-folder`. You would have to replace all the local file system I/O calls in the script with Boto3 S3 API calls. There would be no requirement to run the script on an EC2 instance, although it would generally have a faster connection to S3 than your local computer would.